# UIPicker with multiple components crashing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, ios4, uipickerview

I am trying to create an app using UIPickerView with three components. The first component has 3 rows. The second component has 6 rows and the third component has 12 rows. Every time I scroll beyond row 3 in components 2 or 3 the application crashes and points to the first components array. I'm sure this is easy to fix but I'm lost. Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{    
{
    NSString *resultString0 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                              @"Sensor: %@",
                              [modelArray objectAtIndex:row]];        
    modelLabel.text = resultString0;
    [resultString0 release];   
}
{
    NSString *resultString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                              @"Pixels: %@",
                              [memoryArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    memoryLabel.text = resultString1;
    [resultString1 release];

    NSString *firstString = horizFaceRecLabel.text;
    float horizontalFace = [[horizontalArray objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
    float requiredFace = 100;
    output1 = [firstString floatValue];
    output1 = horizontalFace / requiredFace;
    horizFaceRecLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%.1f ft"), output1];

    NSString *secondString = horizLicensePlateLabel.text;
    float horizontalLicense = [[horizontalArray objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
    float requiredLicense = 45;
    output2 = [secondString floatValue];
    output2 = horizontalLicense / requiredLicense;
    horizLicensePlateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%.1f ft"), output2];

    NSString *thirdString = horizVisualIdLabel.text;
    float horizontalVisual = [[horizontalArray objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
    float requiredVisual = 30;
    output3 = [thirdString floatValue];
    output3 = horizontalVisual / requiredVisual;
    horizVisualIdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%.1f ft"), output3];

}
{
    NSString *resultString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                              @"Lens: %@",
                              [lensArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    lensLabel.text = resultString2;
    [resultString2 release];

    {
        NSString *firstDistString = faceRecLabel.text;
        float angle = [[anglesArrayA objectAtIndex:row] floatValue];
        float densityOne;
        float densityTwo;
        densityOne = [firstDistString floatValue];
        densityTwo = (output1/2)/(sin(angle/2));
        faceRecLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%.1f ft"), densityTwo];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing some `if` statements to control when each block of code gets called.

You have three separate blocks of code presumably for each component but since there's no condition to control the flow, all the blocks get executed whenever a row in any component is selected.  (The third block also has another block inside it--don't know why you've written it like that.)

When you go beyond row 3 in the 2nd and 3rd components, the code for the 1st component runs and crashes when it tries to get the 4th row in the array for component 1 (which doesn't exist).

Since the component indexes are zero-based, the conditions should be something like:

```
if (component == 0)
{
    //code for 1st component here...
}
else if (component == 1)
{
    //code for 2nd component here...
}
else if (component == 2)
{
    //code for 3rd component here...
}
```

You could also use a `switch` statement instead.

Comment: Thanks for you help Anna, I actually originally had the if statements in and it worked ok but wouldn't update all the fields unless I used the component where the actual code was. For example when I use the if statement between the three blocks of code my firstString, secondString, thirdString won't update unless I move component 1. How do I make it update any time any of the components are moved?

Comment: You can get the currently selected row in any component using the `selectedRowInComponent` method which can be called at any time regardless of what component currently changed.  For example: `int currentRowInFirst = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];`.  You can put the component-specific code inside the if-statements and the code that you want to execute every time outside the if-blocks and using selectedRowInComponent.  Note that if no row is currently selected in a component, that method will return -1 so check for that before using it to index an array.

Comment: Just a quick followup. I used the if statements followed by the selectedRowInComponent method and it seems to be working how I want it too. Thanks again for your help